# Spring-security error in config security.xml: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to run this example:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//helloworld-xml.html

I installed a fresh Eclipse Mars.2, JDK 1.8, import the Maven Project and get two errors in security.xml:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'user-service'.
```

I get similar errors in my old Eclipse installation with STS and other plugins installed. I find many references to this problem. All have to do with XML namespaces or a bad project setup. But I am using the a fresh install with the example used in the main spring security tutorial, so it should work without changes. What can I do?

Thanks,
Ropo

Answer (score 1):

Problem went away after adding "-4.1" to the schema:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">
```